# how to add color animation to QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I need to add color animation to QTreeWidgetItem, but in my code, it raise some error, can anyone help me?

The code sample is here:

```py
class TreeWigetItem(QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    @pyqtProperty(QBrush)
    def bcolor(self):
        return self.background(0)

    @bcolor.setter
    def bcolor(self, color):
        self.setBackground(0, color)
        self.setBackground(1, color)
```

and call method like this:

```py
child_item = TreeWigetItem()
self.child_item_ani = QPropertyAnimation(child_item, b'bcolor')
self.child_item_ani.setDuration(1000)
self.child_item_ani.setEndValue(QBrush(Qt.red))
self.child_item_ani.start()
```

erros here:

```
self.child_item_ani = QPropertyAnimation(child_item, b'bcolor')  
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:  
  QPropertyAnimation(parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'TreeWigetItem'  
  QPropertyAnimation(QObject, Union[QByteArray, bytes, bytearray], parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'TreeWigetItem'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html)(pyqtProperty in PyQt) are only valid in the QObjects, but in this case [`QTreeWidgetItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html) does not inherit from QObject so the [`QPropertyAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html) will not work either. So instead of using [`QPropertyAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html) you should use [`QVariantAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html) as I show below:

```py
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class TreeWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem):
    @property
    def animation(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_animation"):
            self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
            self._animation.valueChanged.connect(self._on_value_changed)
        return self._animation

    def _on_value_changed(self, color):
        for i in range(self.columnCount()):
            self.setBackground(i, color)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(columnCount=2)

    it = TreeWidgetItem(["Foo", "Bar"])

    # setup animation
    it.animation.setStartValue(QtGui.QColor("white"))
    it.animation.setEndValue(QtGui.QColor("red"))
    it.animation.setDuration(5 * 1000)
    it.animation.start()

    # add item to QTreeWidget
    w.addTopLevelItem(it)

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: your suggest work fine, buf if i change my origin code as `class TreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem, QObject)` to inherit QObject, i think it will also work, but  i run my code in cmd line, the app gone away without any error?

Comment: @jie Multiple inheritance in PyQt is limited for some cases and QTreeWidgetItem is not within them: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#multiple-inheritance

Comment: i had click up arrow before , for a long time i think it is to mark good answer, today i had see a check label below the down-arrow.